# Calling WebService using Quartz

Tags: c#, web-services, quartz

I have tasks that need to run every hour inifite times.

So far I have added Quartz.NET into my project which runs tasks every hour, however since the HttpContext is required to run these tasks, using Quartz to do this you can imagine that the HttpContext is null hence throwing exceptions.

I've got a workaround in my head in which I would create a web service and the Quartz scheduler would call the web service every hour, the web service would be the only thing dealing with tasks that require the HttpContext.

Since I can't find anything related online anywhere im starting to think whether if this is possible? If it is possible, how would you go about calling the web service?

Comment: and for what do you need that HttpContext?

Comment: A Web service client running on a quartz schedule? Done it and implemented it.

Comment: Any example of how to call a web service on quartz?